# MIME and Processing Feedback Loop Messages

Tags: .net, mime, feedback-loop

I'm trying to process Feedback Loop (FBL) messages to unsubscribe people that mark an email as spam (yes it's opt-in, and there is a one-click opt-out mechanism).

My first attempt is to use [Advanced MIME Parser/Creator/Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mime_project.aspx?msg=3247847#xx3247847xx). However, FBL messages from major ISPs such as AOL and Yahoo are not correctly parsed.  I posted that particular issue directly to the project's discussion forum.

My two-part question for the SO community:

- Is there another MIME processing library for .NET that I'm missing?
- Is there a good explanation of the MIME message format for non-SMTP experts out there?  My Google searches turn up things that are either incomplete, or written assuming the reader is already very familiar with SMTP and email handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced MIME Parser/Creator/Editor never worked correctly for me.  A commercial library is not an option for this task.

I ended up just properly decoding the MIME message (be sure to properly handle line breaks) and looking for relevant keywords.   That worked fine for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

My team has been using Rebex Secure Mail for .NET for two years and it is really solid. Our service (http://nutshellmail.com/) pulls down millions of POP3 and IMAP messages across all major ISPs on a daily basis. Rebex successfully parses the headers of all these messages. We also use Rebex for our outbound SMTP needs.

The full version of SecureMail is $350 (though for your purposes you could probably get away with the $250 POP3-only version). We have hit some obscure problems in the past (i.e. GoDaddy's POP3 servers not fully complying with RFC1939); Rebex support was extremely responsive and quickly provided us with a patch.

Rebex Secure Mail: http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Hunny Software. http://www.hunnysoft.com/ I've used their MIME libraries in the past and have had great experience with them.